# Debian VIA driver problem

Tags: debian, debian-lenny, mouse, via

my system is

motherboard - k8v-vm ultra
vga compatible controller - k8m890ce/k8n890ce[chrome 9] via technologies

downloaded via driver for the debian lenny system from
http://www.via.com.tw/en/support/drivers.jsp 
and the driver file is 
http://www.viaarena.com/Driver/via_linux_cn896&k8m890&p4m900&vn896_kernel_source_ig_v0.82.gz

the driver was installed successfully according to the instructions given in the downloaded source file

the max resolution of 1920x1080 on my acer h235h is got when via is specified as the driver in device section in xorg.conf, but when the x loads the mouse cursor becomes invisible

i need help to get the mouse cursor visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had encountered d same problem.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenChrome

In the above link solution is provided for **openchrome** driver.
U can try it for **via** driver.

Try
**Option "*SWCursor*" "*true*"**
in **device** *section* of **xorg.conf**

This solved my problem and should solve yours too.

To know more about **hardware cursor** and **software cursor** check the documentation in www.x.org